# run.bat file results in .jar program errors

Tags: java, batch-file, classnotfoundexception

Error message when I click the `run.bat`

```
C:\Users\Jessica\Pictures\2023\Roger\scraper\scraper>echo off

C:\Users\Jessica\Pictures\2023\Roger\scraper\scraper>java -cp scrape-shopify-products-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;. org.play.ScrapeShopifyProducts  1>output_02_1451.csv
Error: Could not find or load main class org.play.ScrapeShopifyProducts
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.play.ScrapeShopifyProducts
```

Output is blank

Got a small program written, then the code changed and I had to make another `.jar` file. I was and told to download Maven, and chocolatey, which I did. I updated Maven and Java, and eventually Maven worked.

We are running it through Windows Command Prompt, which I want to still do.

I was told to run it with the `run.bat` file that we were using, but I got errors. I changed the name of the .jar file in the `run.bat` file using Notepad, but got errors again or no output.

Comment: Hi @kerbermeister .... Did someone delete the other answer that was helpful that was there yesterday? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Compo I see that yesterday you edited my question and then replied with advice to help which I was applying but today it seems to have been deleted or taken away ... Is everything okay?

Comment: @kerbermeister - what do you want to know to assist ? It depends on what details you are asking for as well? I just am asking for assistance thanks

Comment: @kerbermeister - error message when I click run.bat : Error: Could not find or load main class and Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Comment: we have no idea what your main class is, what your app is, how your code looks like, how you compiled it and etc. How do you want us to understand your problem?

Comment: @kerbermeister okay ... I understand what you are saying. I dont feel comfortable/scared to post all that no offense. Sorry. Please understand. Appreciate your feedback though. Thanks a lot. Regards Jessica

Comment: Jessica, actually I don't really understand your reaction. The error you got literally means what it says - the main class could not be found. And that's all what we can say here, seeing what you have posted and described in your question. What I wanted to convey you is that we need to see your project structure, your main class, your pom.xml and information how you compiled your project. Didn't mean to offend you at all. Just provide more information, so that we can help you. Peace.